# SwiftUI: The Structured Editing Popover (Command + Click) does not show up

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI tutorial ([link](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views)) it says to:

> Command-click the text view’s initializer to show the structured editing popover, and then choose Embed in VStack

However, it does not work for me.

What is the command for that?
What that deprecated already?

Answer (score 26):

If it helps someone out there, you must have changed Xcode shortcut preferences to go to "Definition" on "Command Click".
So now for seeing the structured editing popover, use "Control Command Click".

Comment: I can confirm this was the case for me.

Check in Xcode > Preferences > Navigation

Comment: Incredible find - would love to know how you remembered to check there.

Comment: It clicked after some hours of pulling out my hair :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice! For me it helped go to Xcode > Preferences > Navigation and change "Option-click on code" to "Shows Swift UI inspector".

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be an Xcode quirk caused by having the canvas hidden. Bring the preview canvas back on screen and the <kbd>Command</kbd> + Click functionality returns to normal:

[image]

I've seen similar weirdness with two Xcode windows open… especially if one window is hiding the Preview.

Another quirk mentioned above: the Library picker is missing the Views and Modifiers tab sometimes. Again, open the Preview Canvas and the Library will snap back to normal. You might also have to bring focus to the canvas (i.e. click on something there).

[image]

Comment: Your answer is correct and already has helped me, but isn't it too verbose?

Answer (score 4):

Your canva must be on **Selectable Mode** (works for me on the latest version of Xcode)

Go to **Editor** and check **Canva**. Below the canva, you have many icons like zoom etc.. Select the "Selectable" icon, it would be the second icon.

[show here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhsz3.png)

Tell me if it works

Comment: Worked for me, thanks very much!  Seems like the tutorial needs updating...

Answer (score 1):

Close and reopen Xcode should help. Like code completion sometimes is not working the popover also sometimes stuck.

Comment: I restarted multiple times but it did not work.  But I see a wheel spinning the first time I try after restarting. It might be my Mac or my Xcode version (as I’m using the beta version to test SwiftUI).

Answer (score 1):

I found that `command + Left Click` on Text (within the .swift file) took me to the definition of Text, however `command + Right Click` caused the menu containing "everything" to appear, from which I was then able to select "Show in UISwift inspector".

I couldn't get anything to popup in the Canvas.

Using Xcode 12.2 on macOS 11.0.1

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 15, just right-click then the Structured Editing Popover will appear, please refer tho the following image https://imgur.com/HiOb0L3

That's it.

You might not see screenshots, since I am new and have zero reputation to post images.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's release notes for the latest Xcode 11 beta release, the inspector and preview features don't currently work without MacOS Catalina 10.15 (the current stable/public release is MacOS 10.14.6 at the time of posting).

You'll either need to wait until the publicly released version of Mac OS 10.15 or gain access to a beta version of MacOS to use these.

Source ([Apple | Xcode 11 Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes)):

> Xcode 11 supports development with SwiftUI. (22843503)
>
> Note: SwiftUI previews and inspectors are only available when running on macOS Catalina 10.15.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and found that when the View Initializer is in Live Preview (the play button at the top of the preview pressed), command clicking a preview element doesn't open the structured menu (the preview isn't responsive to the command click). However, when pausing Live Preview, the view initializer becomes responsive to command clicking - i.e. the structured menu appears and the Embed VStack command accessible.

Answer (score -1):

Restart the project for 1 or 2 times and CMD+B(Build) your project one the start.

[image: Sample]